# Open Server - Запуск сервера в текущей папке без виртуального диска невозможен

Tags: openserver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он у меня дико тормозит когда на виртуальном диске. И хочу чтобы он работал с диска на прямую.

После того как поменял настройки уже не запускается и выдает ошибку

- Запуск сервера в текущей папке без виртуального диска невозможен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автоопределение потребности -  решило вопрос [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь не создает виртуальный диск и не тормозит !